# why isn't my div showing up?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, iteration

So I've created an erb block that iterates through a set of images, and then displays div.tagged for each image at the given coordinates. In this particular case the block iterates through 1 image, however div.tagged does not show up on the page. When I inspect element .tagged is there, but does not actually display. Anyone have any ideas as to why? [Here is the HTML that is generated.](https://gist.github.com/filkinsteez/6050853) [And here is a screen shot of the inspected element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8NL4.png)

ERB:

```
<div class="container">

<% if @new_manual.present? %>
<% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
    <% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>
        <span class="i_connection" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>" data-image=> </span>
<br>

<div class="image_panel">
    <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
<div class='i_connection'></div>
</div>

<% end %>   
<% end %>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("span.i_connection").each(function() {
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = $(this).data('pos-y');

    $(".tagged_box").css("display","block");
    $(".tagged").css("border","5px solid red");


        $('.i_connection').append('<div class="tagged"   style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+pos_height+'px;left:'+xpos+'px;top:'+ypos+'px;" ><div class="tagged_box" style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+
            pos_height+'px;" style="position:absolute;"></div>')
}); 
});
```

CSS:

```
.i_connection div{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}

.image_panel{
  float:left;
  width:600px;
  position:relative;
}
.image_panel img{
  left:0;top:0px;
  max-width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: you are saying div tagged is not displaying but you are giving css code from other divs.. I would put css for `tagged` div too

Comment: You should be able to debug this easier than we will be able to by reading your code. With chrome inspect you can edit CSS and HTML properties, have a play around until you can get it to show, consider `z-index`, perhaps?

Comment: I put this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcYNR/3/) and I have not been able to see anything in your span `.i_connection` tag.

Comment: The css for tagged is styled right in the jQuery, and I've tried playing with the z-index and absolute positioning, still no luck.

Comment: @Yasky Exactly my problem. If you inspect the image, .tagged is there it's just not showing up

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kcYNR/5/) out; same jsfiddle, 5th iteration.

The HTML string used in the `.append()` was not properly nested. There was a missing closing `</div>`tag. Also, feared there was some quote unbalancing going on. I decided to use the jQuery alternative to build the HTML.

I assumed you wanted to nest `.tagged_box` in `.tagged`. If this assumption is wrong, you should change

```
_tagged.append(_tagged_box);
$('div.i_connection').append(_tagged);
```

...to...

```
$('div.i_connection').append(_tagged_box);
$('div.i_connection').append(_tagged);
```

...in whichever order you wish.

p.s: you may want to look for another class name for the inner `.i_connection` because the jQuery seector matches the parent span and the inner div.

Cheers.